# calling id from applet object throws js error in IE

Tags: java, javascript, object, applet

When calling an applet id from JS giving `Object doesn't support this property or method` error.

Please check the code...

```
<!--[if !IE]> Firefox and others will use outer object -->
    <object
        classid     = "java:com.mypack.myclass.ABCClass.class"
        type        = "application/x-java-applet"
        height      = "200"
        width       = "480"
        id          = "myappletId">
        <!-- Konqueror browser needs the following param -->
        <param name="cache_archive" value="a.jar, b.jar, c.jar" />
        <param name="codebase" value="applets/" />
        <param name="OnMouseLeftClickJS" value="showModal()">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <!-- MSIE (Microsoft Internet Explorer) will use inner object -->
        <object 
            classid     = "clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
            codebase    = "http://java.sun.com/update/1.5.0/jinstall-1_5_0-windows-i586.cab"
            height      = "200"
            width       = "480"
            id          = "myappletId">
            <param name="code" value="com.mypack.myclass.ABCClass" />
            <param name="cache_archive" value="a.jar, b.jar, c.jar" />
            <param name="OnMouseLeftClickJS" value="showModal()">
            <param name="codebase" value="applets/" />
            <strong>No Java Support</strong>
        </object>
        <!--[if !IE]> close outer object -->
    </object>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Now, in my showModal() js function I have,

```
var myId = document.getElementById("myappletId"); //At this point I am getting the object data.
```

I perform some operations in my modal window which is a jquery modal window and I have a button in it. When I click on that I am calling a function say xyz().

```
function xyz() {
    var myId = document.getElementById("myappletId"); 
    //At this point myId is getting empty.
}
```

This is happening in only IE Browser. I tested in IE8.
Works good in Firefox and chrome.

I am not navigating my page and on view source I can see my object tag.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try using the deployJava.js linked from the [applet info. page.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) It is the script supplied & supported by the suppliers of the Java Plug-In.  It will also side-step the entire inner/outer complication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your effort guys, the mistake is in my code. When I open a modal window making the object tag visibility hidden in the back. Even I am make it visible after closing the modal window, This IE is not identifying it. Weird but true...

Answer (score 0):

In your comments you have

```
<!-- MSIE (Microsoft Internet Explorer) will use inner object -->
```

How about using `document.getElementById('myappletId').getElementById('innerApplet')` ?
It would be great idea to use unique id for inner applet, maybe then your solution would work.

Comment: actually myappletId is referring to inner applet only. That means depending on the browser for IE or Firefox it refers to only one id based on the comment specified. Just to remind from the code above, my first call is working perfectly.